# How can i update a List inside Update function using [ExecuteInEditMode]?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine;

[ExecuteInEditMode]
public class AnimationCamera : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string test;
    public Camera animationCamera;
    public Camera mainCamera;
    private Animator _anim;
    public List<AnimationClip> animations = new List<AnimationClip>();

    private void Start()
    {
        test = "daniel";
        animationCamera.enabled = false;
        mainCamera.enabled = true;
        _anim = GetComponent<Animator>();       
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        _anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
        foreach (AnimationClip ac in _anim.runtimeAnimatorController.animationClips)
        {
            animations.Add(ac);
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.C))
        {
            animationCamera.enabled = !animationCamera.enabled;
            mainCamera.enabled = !mainCamera.enabled;

            if (animationCamera.enabled)
            {
                _anim.CrossFade("Animation_Sign", 0);
            }
            else
            {
                _anim.CrossFade("Animation_Idle", 0);
            }
        }
    }

    public IEnumerator PlaySignAnimation()
    {
        animationCamera.enabled = true;
        _anim.CrossFade("Animation_Sign", 0);
        yield return null; //new WaitForSeconds(animations[0]);
        animationCamera.enabled = false;
        mainCamera.enabled = true;

    }
}
```

The way it is now it will update the animations List all the time and will keep adding the same item to the List in the editor.
Since in the editor i will update the Animator window i want it to automatic update the animations list each time i add or remove animation clip from/to the Animator window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The way it is now it will update the animations List all the time and
>   will keep adding the same item to the List in the editor.

The simple fix is to add `ac` to the animations `List` only if it does not exist in the animations `List`.

Change:

```
foreach (AnimationClip ac in _anim.runtimeAnimatorController.animationClips)
{
    animations.Add(ac);
}
```

to

```
foreach (AnimationClip ac in _anim.runtimeAnimatorController.animationClips)
{
    if (!animations.Contains(ac))
    {
        animations.Add(ac);
    }
}
```

There might be other ways but this seems simple enough.

**EDIT**:

As for checking when the animation clip is modified, you can subscribe to the [`AnimationUtility.OnCurveWasModified`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AnimationUtility.OnCurveWasModified.html) delegate function.